# Escaping @ character in password

Tags: java, url, escaping

I'm trying to make an authenticated request using java's URL object. The problem is that I have the `@` symbol in my password (changing it is not an option right now), so when java tries the `url.getUserInfo()` it stops at the `@` in the password and screws up my request. I tried escaping it with `%40` but from what I see in debug mode it sees it as just `%40` and not as an `@` character.

Example: `http://user:p@ss@stackoverflow.com` will take the userinfo as `user:p`

Comment: It's a failure in the URL scheme to account for this particular scenario. There's absolutely nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than putting the username and password in the URL, you could register an [Authenticator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Authenticator.html) that is able to provide the credentials when required.

```
Authenticator.setDefault(new Authenticator() {
  protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
    if("stackoverflow.com".equals(getRequestingHost()) {
      return new PasswordAuthentication("user", "p@ss".toCharArray());
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`?os_username=user&os_password=p@ss` this is what I found works as an alternative so your request will be authenticated and look like this: 
`http://stackoverflow.com/stuff?os_username=user&os_password=p@ss`